# Unexpected PCA scores in R

Tags: r, pca

Given a data matrix M, pc=prcomp(M) provides pc$rotation (a matrix of eigenvectors) and pc$x, the scores of the original variables in the pca space. However, the scores I obtain don't match inner products computed "by hand."

For instance, if I have matrix

```
m1=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,4,8,7,9,5,3,2,11),byrow=TRUE,nrow=3)
```

`pctest=prcomp(m1)` returns the following for pctest$x, pctest$rotation, respectively:

```
Rotation:
          PC1        PC2        PC3
    [1,] -0.3751603  0.3133237 -0.5240612
    [2,] -0.5810952 -0.4802203  0.5681371
    [3,] -0.3471051 -0.5836868 -0.6211215
    [4,] -0.6333255  0.5749142  0.1295694


pctest$x
           PC1       PC2           PC3
     [1,]  5.11167 -1.326545 -1.110223e-16
     [2,] -4.05543 -2.728072 -1.942890e-15
     [3,] -1.05624  4.054616  2.831069e-15
```

Now, the score of variable 1 on PCA axis 2 (for instance) should just be the inner product of m1[1,] on pctest$rotation[,2], which is

```
        m1[1,]%*%pctest$rotation[,2]
        [,1]
        [1,] -0.09852071
```

Rather than pctest$x[1,2], which is -1.3265

Is this just a matter of scaling, or is $x returning something other than the projections of the original variables onto the PCA axes?

Comment: +1 for a clear and concise question with reproducible code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation for `?prcomp` answers your question: *The calculation is done by a singular value decomposition of the (centered and possibly scaled) data matrix...*

You would need to center and scale `m1[1,]` before you can multiply it with the corresponding PCA vector. This can be readily observed by setting the `center` and `scale` arguments to `FALSE` after which:

```
all.equal(m1 %*% pctest$rotation, pctest$x)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: If you make this into answer, a more to-the-point answer would be more appropriate. A more vague hint like this works best as a comment, as you already did.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. The score for each variable should still be its projection onto the PCA vectors. When I take the inner product of the variables in m (say, m1[1,]) and the corresponding PCA vector (regardless of whether it's an eigenvector or computed from SVA decomposition), I do not obtain the scores in pca$x.

Comment: @user1815498: the point is that the calculation is done on the _centered and possibly scaled_ data matrix.  You have to center and scale `m1[1,]` before you can multiply it with the corresponding PCA vector.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: you weren't supposed to see that. Funny you say that though, since others often tell me I should post my comments as answers. I'm so confused. :)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I'm so fast ;)

Comment: I'll see if I can replicate the results by hand if I set center=FALSE and scale=FALSE.

Comment: I approve of @PaulHiemstra's answer, especially the `FASLE`. :)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich can we share the rep? I would deserve at least 23.1% for editing in my things :). And what better than to use `FASLE` for `FALSE`, like using vault for fault.